# Python: Modules Importing other Modules

Tags: python, python-2.7, module

I have to import quite a few modules that are not preinstalled with python 2.7. Because my main.py file gets messy quickly and I need error handling (to check if all the modules are installed) I have created a separate module called config which looks somewhat like this:

```
#Import2: module1
try:
    import module1
except(ImportError):
    print ErrorModule1
except:
    print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
```

In my main file, I imported the module like so:

```
from config import *
```

Even so, although my config-file is able to import Module1, the imported Module1 does not get passed to the main-file. Is there any way to do that?

Thanks for your help,
Narusan

Comment: Be more specific, what is the config-file and what is the main script? ...

Comment: main file = main.py; config file = module. Sorry for that, I edited the question, is it understandable now?